# How to open a specific native Mac OS, Windows and Linux system folder through Flutter desktop?

Tags: linux, windows, flutter, macos, dart

I need to open a native system specific folder similar to the image below with Flutter desktop:

`FilePicker` package doesn't work as it opens a "random" folder and I need it to be a specific folder

[image]

This is a Mac OS example, but I need it to open on Windows and Linux as well.

Answer (score 1):

you can use package [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker), it support all platforms for your need.

```
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();

if (result != null) {
  File file = File(result.files.single.path);
} else {
  // User canceled the picker
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need a specific folder to be opened. This package does not meet that need.

Answer (score 0):

```
file_picker: ^4.4.0
```

[pub.dev filepicker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker)
[image]

This package work on all platform  marked

**Single file**

```
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();

if (result != null) {
  File file = File(result.files.single.path);
} else {
  // User canceled the picker
}
```

**Multiple files**

```
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(allowMultiple: true);

if (result != null) {
  List<File> files = result.paths.map((path) => File(path)).toList();
} else {
  // User canceled the picker
}
```

**In Windows Like this:**

[image]

**Full Sample Code:**

```
import 'dart:io';


import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();




  runApp(MaterialApp(home: sta()));
}

// eyJlcnJvciI6IlVOS05PV05fRVJST1IifQ==
class sta extends StatefulWidget {
  const sta({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<sta> createState() => _staState();
}



class _staState extends State<sta> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // MediaQuery(
    //     data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
    //       textScaleFactor: 1.0,
    //     ),
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    child: OutlinedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Filepick();
                      },
                      child: Text("Pick File"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),

          ],
        ));
  }

  Future<void> Filepick() async {
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();

    if (result != null) {
      File file = File(result.files.single.path ?? "");
    } else {
      // User canceled the picker
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need a specific folder to be opened. This package does not meet that need.